# English translation of Fouxe-Rabinovitch paper

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups, translation

Is there somewhere an english translation of Fouxe-Rabinovitch's papers

"D. I. Fouxe-Rabinovitch, Uber die Automorphismengruppen ¨
der freien Produkte. II, Rec. Math. [Mat. Sbornik] N.S., 1941,
Volume 9(51), Number 1, 183–220"

and

"D. I. Fouxe-Rabinovitch, Uber die Automorphismengruppen ¨
der freien Produkte. I, Rec. Math. [Mat. Sbornik] N.S., 1940,
Volume 8(50), Number 2, 265–276
" ??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is the [Russian original](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=6055&option_lang=eng) and the German translation, but you could try Google Translate if you need any other language.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker Ok, thank you!